# Error while deploying SAP Fiori and CAPM application in SAP BTP Trial Account

Tags: node.js, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-business-technology-platform, sap-cap

I created a basic **SAP CAP/Fiori application** using BAS of SAP BTP, with HANA DB Instance created. It's working fine when I run it locally. However, during deployment to SAP BTP Trial Account, I encountered the issue/error below.

After deployment was completed with errors, the **SAP CAP Service** is working fine, only the **SAP Fiori** which is not working since an error was encountered during deployment.

### **Error encountered during deployment**

```
Error starting application "Bookshop2": Some instances have crashed. Check the logs of your application for more information.
Download the application logs via the dmol command and check them for more information.
A step of the process has failed. Retrying it may solve the issue.
Proceeding with automatic retry... (3 of 3 attempts left)
```

### **Content of dmol(Logs)**

*Inside **dmol**, an error **Cannot open: No space left on device** was encountered.*

```
######org.cloudfoundry.multiapps.controller.persistence.services.ProcessLogger########flowable-async-job-executor-thread-8326###
[PollStageAppStatusExecution] [Bookshop2] 238506b3-8a7f-415f-bcab-7c8de217ee09 [2023-04-19T16:44:37.035921] Copying droplet into the container failed: stream-in: nstar: error streaming in: exit status 2. Output: tar: ./app/bookshop/node_modules/@sap/di.code-validation.xml/src/fioriAnalysis/ui5Versions/1.60.13/_sap.m.json: Wrote only 512 of 10240 bytes (STDERR, CELL)#

#2.0#2023 04 19 17:15:28.108#Z#DEBUG#com.sap.cloud.lm.sl.xs2.783edf34-ded5-11ed-8416-eeee0a9a8355.Bookshop2.stageAppTask#
######org.cloudfoundry.multiapps.controller.persistence.services.ProcessLogger########flowable-async-job-executor-thread-8326###
[PollStageAppStatusExecution] [Bookshop2] 238506b3-8a7f-415f-bcab-7c8de217ee09 [2023-04-19T16:44:37.035939] tar: ./app/bookshop/node_modules/@sap/di.code-validation.xml/src/fioriAnalysis/ui5Versions/1.60.13/_sap.ui.commons.json: Cannot open: No space left on device (STDERR, CELL)#
```

### **Steps for deployment**

```
Cds add hana –for production
Cds add xsuaa –for production
Cds add mta (Optional in case you don’t have it yet.)
Cds add approuter –for production
It will generate xs-app and default-env.json inside /app folder. 
Npm install

Cds build –production
Mbt build -t gen –mtar mta.tar

cf login
cf deploy gen/mta.tar
```

### **Code Snippet**

A code snippet use for creating a basic Fiori/CAP application.

---

**mta.yaml**

```
ID: Bookshop2
description: A simple CAP project.
version: 1.0.0
modules:
  - name: Bookshop2-srv
    type: nodejs
    path: gen/srv
    provides:
      - name: srv-api
        properties:
          srv-url: ${default-url}
    parameters:
      buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
    build-parameters:
      builder: npm-ci
    requires:
      - name: Bookshop2-db
      - name: Bookshop2-auth
  - name: Bookshop2-app-content
    type: com.sap.application.content
    path: .
    requires:
      - name: Bookshop2-repo-host
        parameters:
          content-target: true
    build-parameters:
      build-result: resources
      requires:
        - artifacts:
            - combookshopfioribookshop.zip
          name: combookshopfioribookshop
          target-path: resources/
  - name: combookshopfioribookshop
    type: html5
    path: app/bookshop
    build-parameters:
      build-result: dist
      builder: custom
      commands:
        - npm install
        - npm run build:cf
      supported-platforms:
        []

  - name: Bookshop2-db-deployer
    type: hdb
    path: gen/db
    parameters:
      buildpack: nodejs_buildpack
    requires:
      - name: Bookshop2-db

  - name: Bookshop2
    type: approuter.nodejs
    path: app/ # from cds.env.folders. Consider also cds.env.build.target -> gen/app
    parameters:
      keep-existing-routes: true
      disk-quota: 256M
      memory: 256M
    requires:
      - name: srv-api
        group: destinations
        properties:
          name: srv-api # must be used in xs-app.json as well
          url: ~{srv-url}
          forwardAuthToken: true
      - name: Bookshop2-auth
resources:
  - name: Bookshop2-repo-host
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
      service: html5-apps-repo
      service-name: Bookshop2-html5-srv
      service-plan: app-host
  - name: Bookshop2-destination-service
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
      config:
        HTML5Runtime_enabled: false
        init_data:
          instance:
            destinations:
              - Authentication: NoAuthentication
                Name: ui5
                ProxyType: Internet
                Type: HTTP
                URL: https://ui5.sap.com
            existing_destinations_policy: update
        version: 1.0.0
      service: destination
      service-name: Bookshop2-destination-service
      service-plan: lite
  - name: Bookshop2-db
    type: com.sap.xs.hdi-container
    parameters:
      service: hana
      service-plan: hdi-shared
  - name: Bookshop2-auth
    type: org.cloudfoundry.managed-service
    parameters:
      service: xsuaa
      service-plan: application
      path: ./xs-security.json
      config:
        xsappname: Bookshop2-${org}-${space}
        tenant-mode: dedicated
parameters:
  deploy_mode: html5-repo
  enable-parallel-deployments: true
build-parameters:
  before-all:
    - builder: custom
      commands:
        - npx -p @sap/cds-dk cds build --production
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "Bookshop2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple CAP project.",
  "repository": "<Add your repository here>",
  "license": "UNLICENSED",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@sap/cds": "^6",
    "express": "^4",
    "hdb": "^0.19.0",
    "@sap/xssec": "^3",
    "passport": "^0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@sap/ux-specification": "^1.108.3",
    "sqlite3": "^5",
    "rimraf": "^3.0.2"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "^16"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "cds-serve",
    "watch-bookshop": "cds watch --open bookshop/webapp/index.html?sap-ui-xx-viewCache=false",
    "undeploy": "cf undeploy Bookshop2 --delete-services --delete-service-keys --delete-service-brokers",
    "build": "rimraf resources mta_archives && mbt build --mtar archive",
    "deploy": "cf deploy mta_archives/archive.mtar --retries 1"
  },
  "sapux": [
    "app/bookshop"
  ],
  "cds": {
    "requires": {
      "[production]": {
        "db": {
          "kind": "hana-cloud"
        },
        "auth": {
          "kind": "xsuaa"
        },
        "approuter": {
          "kind": "cloudfoundry"
        }
      },
      "db": {
        "kind": "sql"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**db/domain-model.cds**

```
namespace com.bookshop2;

entity Books {
    key ID  : Integer;
    title   : String(100);
    stock   : Integer;
    price   : Decimal(9,2);
    author  : Association to Authors;
}

entity Authors {
    key ID  : Integer;
    name    : String(100);
    books   : Composition of many Books on books.author = $self;
}
```

**srv/service.cds**

```
using { com.bookshop2 as bookshop } from '../db/domain-model';

service AdminService {
    entity Books as projection on bookshop.Books;
    entity Authors as projection on bookshop.Authors;
}
```

**SAP UI5 / Fiori App**

Basic Freestyle or Any Fiori Element Template.

**SAUI5 ui5.yaml**

```
metadata:
  name: com.bookshop.fiori.bookshop
type: application
```

**SAPUI5 ui5-deploy.yaml**

```
specVersion: '2.4'
metadata:
  name: com.bookshop.fiori.bookshop
type: application
resources:
  configuration:
    propertiesFileSourceEncoding: UTF-8
builder:
  resources:
    excludes:
      - "/test/**"
      - "/localService/**"
  customTasks:
  - name: webide-extension-task-updateManifestJson
    afterTask: replaceVersion
    configuration:
      appFolder: webapp
      destDir: dist
  - name: ui5-task-zipper
    afterTask: generateCachebusterInfo
    configuration:
      archiveName: combookshopfioribookshop
      additionalFiles:
      - xs-app.json
```

### **Update: Solution to the Deployment Issue.**

You need to change the **disk-quota** and **memory** of your Fiori/SAUI5 app from **256M** to at least **1024MB**.
[image]

Comment: What's in your fiori ui5.yaml and the other relevant files? What's the build command? Any chance you can find `combookshopfioribookshop.zip` and see what's going on in there?

Comment: Hi @Jorg, I have updated my question with the corresponding ui5.yaml files and my deploy process. Thank you.

Comment: For those who encountered this deployment issue to SAP BTP, I have updated my question to solve the issue. Kindly see the last detail of question to get the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have managed to solve the deployment issue with the help of SAP Experts by changing the **disk-quota** and **memory** of SAPUI5/Fiori App of **mta.yaml** file from **256M** to **1024MB**.

[image]